# Lookup filter information

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lookup-filter

I have a custom Lookup component that will within another LWC. I need to retrieve the filter information for any lookups that has an active filter.
I was able to retrieve data using getFilteredLookupInfo() and filteredlookupinfo.
If the new custom lookup component results is based off a value that is selected on the original LWC. What information do I need from the filter to populate the new lookup component?
For example the field metadata is this:

```
 <filterItems>
        <field>$Source.Account__c</field>
        <operation>equals</operation>
        <valueField>BrokerAccount__c.Account__c</valueField>
    </filterItems>
```

Do I need to be able to get the valueField?
Thanks,
P

Comment: David, using the filteredlookupinfo.getControllingFields() caused the component not to load. Also using filteredlookupinfo.dependent or filteredlookupinfo.controllingfields or filteredlookupinfo.isDependent() caused the component not to load.  I am able to retrieve information using just getFilteredLookupInfo() or filteredlookupinfo().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the tooling API and implementing the API in apex to achieve the same.

Check the details of the API here

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_lookupfilter.htm

Here is the draft code to get you started, Note the below

- It's not production-ready code.
- Add Error Handling and Unit Tests
- LWC Code is not shown and I focus on only backend code
- I have simplified authentication using vf page. I recommend you look into Connected Apps and Named Credential to make sure you are securely authenticating.

Here we go with detailed code

1. Create a VF page to get you the session, since with LWC Session we do not allow you to access the Tooling API

   ```
   <apex:page contentType="application/json">
     {!$Api.Session_ID}
   </apex:page>
   ```
2. Create a Class to read SessionID from vf and expose as Utility to other apex class

   ```
   public inherited sharing class SessionHelper {
    public static String getSessionId() {
     return Test.isRunningTest()
        ? ''
        : Page.session.getContent().toString().trim();
     }
   }
   ```
3. Create an API client to make outbound apex HTTP callout

   ```
    public inherited sharing class APIClient {
     public static String makeAPICall(String endPoint, String method) {
    try {
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setHeader(
            'Authorization',
            'Bearer ' + SessionHelper.getSessionId()
        );
        request.setTimeout(60000);
        request.setEndpoint(endPoint);
        request.setMethod(method);
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        return response.getBody();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        system.debug('Exception in tooling API Call:' + ex.getMessage());
        return ex.getMessage();
       }
     }
   }
   ```
4. Create an apex class to fetch the LookupFilter Metadata

   ```
   public with sharing class LookupFilterController {

     static String toolingSOQL(string queryString) {
      Double apiVersion = getApiVersion();
      String path = '/tooling/query/?q=' + queryString.replace(' ', '+');
       String endpointurl =
        Url.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm() +
        '/services/data/v' +
        apiVersion +
        path;
       return APIClient.makeAPICall(endpointurl, 'GET');
    }

    static Double getApiVersion() {
      return [
        SELECT ApiVersion
        FROM ApexClass
        ORDER BY ApiVersion DESC
        LIMIT 1
      ]
      .ApiVersion;
    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static string getLookupFilters(String developerName) {
         string toolingsoql =
            'SELECT FullName,' +
            'DeveloperName,' +
            'SourceObject,' +
            'Metadata'
            'FROM LookupFilter ' +
            'WHERE DeveloperName=\'' +
             developerName +
            '\'';
       return toolingSOQL(toolingsoql);
      }
    }
   ```

I have not thoroughly tested the above code but I am hoping it unblocks you!

Comment: Mohith, I tested where i ran a query in dev console against lookupFilter but can I do this in a class?  Also, how do I query against the FilterItem Metadata?  Thank you

Comment: I will produce a more detailed apex code once I get sometime today? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks Mohith, hopefully thit will get me closer to fully resolving my issue,

Comment: @Phuc Added code to help you!

Comment: Thank you Mohith